# sqlite3 bind multiple statement values

Tags: c++, sqlite

Considering:

```
int user_id = 0x01; //dummy
int size_id = 0x01; //dummy

sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
sqlite3 *db;

int rc = sqlite3_open("path_to_database.db", &db);

if( rc != SQLITE_OK ) 
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    return -1;
} 

rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "SELECT id, type, time_registered"
                                " from myTestTable"
                                " where user = ? and size = ?", -1, &stmt, NULL);

if (rc != SQLITE_OK)
{
        throw std::string(sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
        return -1;
}
rc = sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 1, user_id);
if (rc != SQLITE_OK)
{
            std::string errmsg(sqlite3_errmsg(db));
            sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
            throw errmsg;
            return -1;
}
rc = sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 2, size_id);
if (rc != SQLITE_OK)
{
            std::string errmsg(sqlite3_errmsg(db));
            sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
            throw errmsg;
            return -1;
}
 [...]
```

This does work, but it seems not user friendly. I could use snprintf to prepare the statement instead of bind, but I'ld loose safety (even if I shouldn't be facing injection attacks on my local db).

Is there a better way to use sqlite3_bind_TYPES to bind more than one value in statement, with same types (or not if possible) ?

Comment: I don't know any other way to bind multiple values in statements, you are doing it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a c++ wrapper like SQLiteCpp. If you don't like that one, there's a list at the bottom of the github page.

If you prefer to use the c interface you could invert the logic of the bind statements.  This would at least unclutter the code a bit.

```
int rc = sqlite3_open("path_to_database.db", &db);

if( rc != SQLITE_OK ) 
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    return -1;
} 

rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "SELECT id, type, time_registered"
                                " from myTestTable"
                                " where user = ? and size = ?", -1, &stmt, NULL);

if (rc == SQLITE_OK)
    rc = sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 1, user_id);

if (rc == SQLITE_OK)
    rc = sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 2, size_id);

if (rc != SQLITE_OK)
{
        throw std::string(sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
        return -1;
}
[...]
```

Mike